# Перегружается телефон во время выполнения программы

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, view

В общем что происходит. Во время исполнения программы каждую минуту-две (время не одинаковое) телефон не то чтобы перезагружается... Показывает логотип самсунг, грузится и запускается рабочий стол. Тоесть полной перезагрузки не происходит. Иногда даже просто показывается домашний экран и по выключеным приложениям становится понятно что был некий сброс.

Что имеем. Программа секундомер с кучей кастомных вьюшек. Используется поток Thread, в котором из списка arrayList<Runnable> в цикле вызываются runnable.run. Как я понял проблема где в отрисовке, ибо если отключить обновление отрисовки вьюшек секундомера (только просчёт времени и вывод его в лог) всё работает нормально. Вот так вызывается отрисовка (да, каждая вьюшка ещё реализует интерфейс runnable и её я и передаю в список), сам post лежит в run() вьюшки

```
 post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        invalidate();
    }
 });
```

Ну вроде всё, ничего особого в коде больше нет...

Comment: а в логе есть что-либо интересное? Логи ещё хранятся в каталоге `/dev/log`.
А может у Вас какая-нибудь модная прошивка?

Comment: нет, всё окей с прошивкой. Логи ничего подозрительно не выдают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена ) Я как-то не задумываясь в onDraw написал вызов setTypeFace. Что мало того что приводило к тормозам (а я по причине малого опыта даже не знал, должно ли оно так тормозить или это у меня ошибки) так ещё и приводило к такому. Убрал его в конструктор, всё заработало ) Даже подумать не мог что проблема там...

Answer (score 0):

К элементам интерфейса нельзя обращаться из Thread, используйте  AsyncTask
[asynctask](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/149-urok-86-asynctask-znakomstvo-neslozhnyj-primer.html) 
[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: или для начала заменить `invalidate()` на `postInvalidate().` Его можно вызывать с других потоков.

Comment: Дык я с основного потока вызываю - post аналогичен runOnUiThread, а postinvalidate - это тоже самое что и у меня в коде. Плюс я уже когда то писал нечто подобное с сарфейсом и тредами, но всё было окей.
Насчёт asyncTask не знаю, ещё попробую, надо подумать как ещё программу так организовать.

Comment: тогда выложите чуточку больше кода. Может получиться собрать минимальный тестовый пример, который воспроизводит проблему.